# vjust and hjust do not work in annotate in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(data = datae31, aes(x = increased_fitness31, y = increased_fitness26)) +
  geom_point( size = 2) + 
  xlab(NULL) + 
  ylab(NULL) + 
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0, size = 1, color = "grey", linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  coord_equal(xlim=c(-0.3,1.8),ylim=c(-0.3,1.8))+
  annotate(
    "text",
    x = 0.75,
    y = 0.75,
    label = "Group 1",
    family = "serif",
    fontface = "italic",
    colour = "darkred",
    size = 5
  )
```

Above is right and runs well, but when I use vjust/hjust instead of x=/y= to control location of annotate, there is no annotate in below code running:

```
ggplot(data = datae31, aes(x = increased_fitness31, y = increased_fitness26)) +
  geom_point( size = 2) + 
  xlab(NULL) + 
  ylab(NULL) + 
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0, size = 1, color = "grey", linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  coord_equal(xlim=c(-0.3,1.8),ylim=c(-0.3,1.8))+
  annotate(
    "text",
    vjust = 0.5, #only change this
    hjust = 0.5,  #and this
    label = "Group 1",
    family = "serif",
    fontface = "italic",
    colour = "darkred",
    size = 5
  )
```

why? and how to

Comment: Hi, I am not sure to understand. Looking at `?ggplot2::annotate`, there is no `vjust` or `hjust` argument defined for this function. Do you have a reproducible example with an example of this function working with these arguments? Maybe have a look at `ggplot2::geom_text()`. This function might suit your need better.

Comment: @Paul
thank you, I found that annotate are not similaar to geom_text, thus x and y must be appointed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must provide x and y arguments to locate the position of you annotation. Hjust and vjust are are just alignment parameters.
So define both (x,y and hjust, vjust and it will work.

Comment: thank you, I found that annotate are not similaar to geom_text, thus x and y must be appointed!